# redux error in electron-react-boilerplate (Uncaught TypeError: action)

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, flowtype

I have been stuck in this question about 3 days.
simplify the example like this.
when I added "custom" action type and got the error "Uncaught TypeError: action.custom must be a string"
Same code works well on creat-react-app with react-redux.
I can skip annotation of action to run the app, but this question/warning so bothering me:(

```js
// @flow
export const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';
export const DECREMENT_COUNTER = 'DECREMENT_COUNTER';
export type counterStateType = {
  +counter: number
};

type actionType = {
  +type: string,
  +custom: string
};

export default function counter(state: number = 0, action: actionType) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
      return state + 1;
    case DECREMENT_COUNTER:
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```html
combineReducers.js:109 Uncaught TypeError: action.custom must be a string

Expected: string

Actual Value: undefined

Actual Type: void


    at counter (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:2419:54)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/redux/es/combineReducers.js?:45:24)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at assertReducerShape (webpack:///./node_modules/redux/es/combineReducers.js?:43:25)
    at combineReducers (webpack:///./node_modules/redux/es/combineReducers.js?:99:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:2493:48)
    at Object../app/reducers/index.js (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:2521:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:680:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:90:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:2969:17)
    at Object../app/store/configureStore.dev.js (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:3085:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:680:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:90:20)
    at Object../app/store/configureStore.js (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:3098:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:680:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:90:20)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you want to change the existing action adding a payload, or add a new action?

Comment: I want to make it pass through flow runtime by setting up correct action type, don't know how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a question mark:

```
actionType = {
  +type: string,
  +custom?: string
};
```

This should allow you to have action with or without 'custom' property, but the property will always have to be a string

```
{
  type: 'DECREMENT_COUNTER',
  custom: 'three
}
```

I am using

```
type actionType = {
  type: string,
  payload?: Object
};
```

and I am adding the payload I want inside the Object, you may get a warning though because Object is a weak type

Hope this help.